# How to find which script running?

Tags: javascript, css

The spinning circle in browser tab (where favicon would show) indicates something is failing to finish loading on my site. Interminably spinning.

Cannot for the love find what is preventing the site from loading to completion, as visually everything is fully presentable. Is there a way to see what process or script a web page is hung up on?

Comment: Try using browser debugging tools.

Comment: F12, click network, reload. The one that is "Pending" is the one that is still running.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't have the right language to ask clearly, so couldn't find the answer despite search. Developer Tools > Network took me right to it, tyvm.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome: More tools > Developer tools > Network. Reload and look in Status column.